# How do I perform aggregation on date and time in Django?

Tags: python, django

Let's say I have the following simplistic model, for demonstration purposes:

```
class Something(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()  
    time = models.TimeField()  
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField() 
    price = models.DecimalField()
    manufacturer = models.CharField()
```

If I want to get the total count of every manufacturer I can do something like below:

```
Something.objects.all().values("manufacturer").annotate(frequency=Count(field))
```

My aim is to do something similar based on the date and time. For example the total count for every month.

My first thought since there are already data based on the model above is to add a custom property, but you can not use it with `values`.

Next, I thought to add the neccessary fields(day,month,year,...) to the model and add a custom `save` method to calculate them.

Another way is to load the queryset into pandas and do the calculations there.

Is there a more appropriate way to do something like this ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do using this way:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncMonth

Something.objects
      .annotate(month=TruncMonth('timestamp')) # Truncate to month to select
      .values('month') # Group By month
      .annotate(frequency=Count(field))  # Get count
```

Comment: @GiannisIordanou, did this work? If this helped please select this answer. Thanks.